# Make character in tag uppercase and remove tag

Tags: python, string

How to make a character between a tag uppercase?

For example I have this string:

```
string = "<big>t<big>his should be <big>u<big>ppercase"
```

Should result in:

```
This should be Uppercase
```

Comment: I'd have a look at XML parsing. Maybe this can help you out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. Another thing: **remember** that the variable name `str` is reserved!!

Comment: is <big> even a real tag?

Comment: It's not a real tag, just for example.

Comment: Normally you'd expect the closing tag to be `</big>`

Comment: Just a heads up, make sure this is not an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you need to deal with actual xml tags, look at Anton's comment.

Comment: Yes but I have never said that this is xml

Comment: No worries. Just wanted to be sure and didn't want to assume either ways.

Answer (score 1):

Constantly as longest as there's **< big>** in txt remove tags and uppercase the text between them

```
def up(x):
    idx1 = x.index('<big>')
    idx2 = x.index('<big>', idx1+1)

    new_x = x[:idx1]
    new_x += x[idx1+5: idx2].upper()
    new_x += x[idx2+5:]

    return new_x

txt = "<big>t<big>his should be <big>u<big>ppercase"
while '<big>' in txt:
    txt = up(txt)

print(txt) # This should be Uppercase
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

s="<big>t<big>his should be <big>u<big>ppercase"

result = re.finditer('<big>(.)<big>', s)

for i in result:
     s = s.replace(i.group(0), i.group(1).upper())
```

Note:

> Do not use `str` as a name of a variable. `str` is predefined in python.

Answer (score 0):

Those don't look like real xml tags. But assuming the number of `<big>` tags are used correctly, you can split it by tag and apply `upper()` to strings between.

```
text = "<big>t<big>his should be <big>u<big>ppercase"

split_str = text.split('<big>')
result = ''.join([x.upper() if i % 2 else x for i, x in enumerate(split_str)])
```